# Combination filters + quick search with Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I’m trying to combine two Isotope filtering features ([combination filtering via checkbox](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JGKyrY) and [quick search](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wfaGu)) with no luck. My attempt is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJvmaj, which is a combination of both of the mentioned feature's demos.

At the moment the search is set to return `searchResult` and `checkboxResult`, the latter of which isn’t being defined properly in the code I can tell, and there lies my problem: I’m not sure what to set the `checkboxResult` variable to in order for it to target what’s being returned by the checkbox filtering.

Comment: I've since come across a working example of this, here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBpYyr. It's structurally completely different from what I was attempting, so I assume the answer to my question is less a small fix and more of a complete rethinking of the code. Posting here for anyone else who comes across this question searching how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the element includes the text that input in search input or not with `.includes()` and if the element has any of selected class from checkboxs' value.

BTW, next time please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem, not a link to your fiddle or codepen, cause the links would be broken and other users couldn't understand what you asked and the scenario of the question.

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: function() {
        var $this = $(this)
        var checkText = text == '' ? true : $this.text().includes(text)
        var checkClass = inclusives.length == 0 ? true : false;
        $.each(inclusives, function(index, c) {
            var _class = $this.hasClass(c)
            if (_class) {
                checkClass = true;
                return;
            }
        })
        return checkText && checkClass
     }
})
```

```js
// quick search regex
var qsRegex;
var checkboxFilter;

// templating
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'];
var sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
var prices = [10, 20, 30];

createItems();

// init Isotope
var $container = $('#container')

var $output = $('#output');

// filter with selects and checkboxes
var $checkboxes = $('#form-ui input');

function createItems() {

  var $items;
  // loop over colors, sizes, prices
  // create one item for each
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < sizes.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < prices.length; k++) {
        var color = colors[i];
        var size = sizes[j];
        var price = prices[k];
        var $item = $('<div />', {
          'class': 'item ' + color + ' ' + size + ' price' + price
        });
        $item.append('<p>' + size + '</p><p>$' + price + '</p>');
        // add to items
        $items = $items ? $items.add($item) : $item;
      }
    }
  }

  $items.appendTo($('#container'));

}
var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch')

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce(fn, threshold) {
  var timeout;
  threshold = threshold || 100;
  return function debounced() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var args = arguments;
    var _this = this;

    function delayed() {
      fn.apply(_this, args);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold);
  };
}

function Filter() {
  // map input values to an array
  var inclusives = [];
  // inclusive filters from checkboxes
  $checkboxes.each(function(i, elem) {
    // if checkbox, use value if checked
    if (elem.checked) {
      inclusives.push(elem.value);
    }
  });

  // combine inclusive filters
  var filterValue = inclusives.length ? inclusives.join(', ') : '*';

  var text = $quicksearch.val()

  $container.isotope({
    filter: function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      var checkText = text == '' ? true : $this.text().includes(text)
      var checkClass = inclusives.length == 0 ? true : false;
      $.each(inclusives, function(index, c) {
        var _class = $this.hasClass(c)
        if (_class) {
          checkClass = true;
          return;
        }
      })
      return checkText && checkClass
    }
  })
  $output.text(filterValue);
}

$quicksearch.on('input', debounce(function() {
  Filter()
}));

$checkboxes.change(function() {
  Filter()
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
}

.red {
  background: #F33;
}

.blue {
  background: #88F;
}

.green {
  background: #3A3;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

select,
label,
input {
  font-size: 20px;
}

label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#quicksearch {
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<p><input type="text" id="quicksearch" placeholder="Search" /></p>

<div id="form-ui">
  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="red" /> red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="green" /> green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue" /> blue</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="orange" /> orange</label>
  </p>

  <p id="output">--</p>

</div>

<div id="container">
  <!-- items added with JS -->
</div>
```